# Set JList not resizable

Tags: java, swing, layout, jscrollpane, jlist

I got small problem when I add element to JList it resize itself. I think it should add scroll bar to it and stay in default size. Can anyone help me with this?

I got JScrollPane -> JList

Comment: please edit your question with http://sscce.org/,

Comment: The answer is probably 'Use layouts properly'.  For more specific answers, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Problem solved i have to set Loyout to absolute and now all is ok thx Andrew for hint

Answer (score 2):

Not clear for me what did you meant about resize/non_resiziable, I think that you have to read tutorial about [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), example there included implementations for [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)